# Member's function pointer error

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I've a class implemented as below. In the constructor, I get a compilation error. Would you guys please tell my why?

```
class A{

public:
    typedef void (A::*HANDLER)();
    void test1(){
        printf("This is test 1");
    }
    void test2(){
        printf("This is test 2");
    }

    A(){
        HANDLER h= &A::test1; 
        h(); // an error spawn here with the description: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use, pointer to member operator `->*` in this way:

```
(this->*h)();
```

**[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/lH8k1)** of your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

The `g++` error message is more informative:

```
bar.cc: In constructor 'A::A()':
bar.cc:15:11: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'h (...)', e.g. '(... ->* h) (...)'
```

And indeed, if you change your call to `(this->*h)();`, it passes the compiler.